# Golang get raw json from postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, go

I have stored procedure in my postgres db

```
SELECT *FROM get_products()
```

which returns json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "one",
    "addition": "spec1",
    "size": "",
    "category_id": 1,
    "vendor_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "two",
    "addition": "spec2",
    "size": "",
    "category_id": 1,
    "vendor_id": 1
  },

/// ...
]
```

How could I return the result from the procedure without making a struct, cause there can be unknown numbers of fields in json?

I have this code. It works well, when procedure returns table, but not json

```
func (s ProductController) GetAll(c *gin.Context) {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost dbname=postgres sslmode=disable user=postgres")

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT *FROM get_products()")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    allgeneric := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    colvals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    for rows.Next() {
        colassoc := make(map[string]interface{}, len(cols))
        for i, _ := range colvals {
            colvals[i] = new(interface{})
        }
        if err := rows.Scan(colvals...); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        for i, col := range cols {
            colassoc[col] = *colvals[i].(*interface{})
        }
        allgeneric = append(allgeneric, colassoc)
    }

    err2 := rows.Close()
    if err2 !=nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    fmt.Println(allgeneric)

    c.JSON(200, allgeneric)
}
```

It returns something like this

```
[
    {
        "get_products": "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
```

But I need to return json, specified above

**UPDATE**

modified my code to

```
func (s ProductController) GetAll(c *gin.Context) {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost dbname=postgres sslmode=disable user=postgres")

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT *FROM get_products()")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var result []interface{}

    cols, _ := rows.Columns()
    pointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    container := make([]json.RawMessage, len(cols))
    for i, _ := range pointers {
        pointers[i] = &container[i]
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(pointers...)
        result = append(result, container)
    }

    fmt.Println(container)

    c.JSON(200, container)
}
```

now it returns

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "one",
      "addition": "spec1",
      "size": "",
      "category_id": 1,
      "vendor_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "two",
      "addition": "spec2",
      "size": "",
      "category_id": 1,
      "vendor_id": 1
    },
  ]
]
```

Need to remove this inner array

Comment: modified my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query returns a single row with a single column containing the JSON. Use this code to read that single value.

```
row, err := db.QueryRow("SELECT *FROM get_products()")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
var jsonData []byte
if err := row.Scan(&jsonData); err != nil {
        // handle error
}
c.Data(200, "application/json", jsonData)
```

There's no need to decode and encode the JSON. Use the JSON data returned form the database as is.

Comment: row := db.QueryRow("SELECT *FROM get_products()") just corrected this line, and everething works fine. Thank you very match!

Comment: The last one question, How is it properly to pass args to stored procedure, it has 2 args - category_id[] and vendor_id[] ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this solution for this kind of static queries.

First use [`.Prepare`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/pg.v6#DB.Prepare) to create a prepared statement.

```golang
db := gopg.Connect(&options)
pgStmt, err := pg.Prepare("SELECT *FROM get_products()")
if err != nil {
    log.panic(err)
}
```

Now, you can simply get the result

```golang
var jsonData []byte
_, err := pgStmt.QueryOne(gopg.Scan(&jsonData))
if err != nil {
    log.panic(err)
}

c.Data(200, "application/json", jsonData)
```

You can receive json as string also and then convert it into `[]byte`:

```golang
var json string
_, err := pgStmt.QueryOne(gopg.Scan(&json))
if err != nil {
    log.panic(err)
}

// do something with that json

jsonData := []byte(json)
c.Data(200, "application/json", jsonData)
```